# mongodb wildcard query from grails/groovy

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I’m having some problems with issuing a wildcard query in MongoDB from my Grails application.

Basically the way I am doing it now is by issuing a `find` query with an array of query parameters:

```
db.log.find(criteria)    -> where criteria is an array [testId:"test"]
```

This works fine as long as I’m strictly querying on actual values. However, for fun, I tried it with a wildcard search instead:

```
db.log.find(criteria) -> this time critera = [testId:/.*te.*/]
```

This however will after looking at the Mongo query log as:

```
 query: { query: { testId: "/.*te.*/" }
```

hence making the query not a wildcard search, but a query for this as a string, instead.
Is there a way to work around this in some sense still using this concept of querying?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use the Groovy Pattern shortcut `~` to specify that your query is a regular expression.

```
db.log.find(['testId': ~/.*te.*/])
```

See this [blog post](http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2011/01/29/groovy-gmongo-tips-and-tricks/#regex_based_search) for more info

Answer (score 1):

To use regex query, define query condition with $regex [operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/)

```
def regexCondition = ['$regex': '/.*te.*/']
def criteria = ['testId': regexCondition]
db.log.find(criteria)
```

Comment: This does not return me anything running it from the mongo console.
db.log.find( { testId: { $regex: '/.*te.*/' } } )

Comment: its still the same problem of mongo interpreting the query as a string, removing the '', db.log.find({testId:{ $regex: /.*te.*/}})  works fine

Comment: @dunnless `db.log.find({testId:{ $regex: /.*te.*/}})` seems to be a command in mongodb console, but in Grails, the parameters have to be put in BasicDBObject objects first.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
In your groovy file:

```
db.collectionName.find([fieldName:[$regex:'pattern']])
```

More or less, use a regular mongodb query, but replace the {} with [].